# How can I get errors and exceptions ,and write them to log files?

Tags: php

In my PHP project,I want to get all errors and exceptions when in product Server.But how can I get them and wirte them to my log files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a catch block:

```
try {
    foo();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    error_log("Caught $e");
}
```

Or in the exception handler:

```
set_exception_handler(function($exception) {
    error_log($exception);
    error_page("Something went wrong!");
});
```